# Serial console stops output abruptly

Tags: hardware, serial-communication

I've been playing with a device similar to this one: [EPC3208G](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/cisco/epc3208g). 
I've connected GND, TX and what i think is an RX pins via ttl adapter. Using minicom, 8N1 and baudrate of 115200, I managed to get some output after the device powers up. But, much like in the linked article on openwrt wiki, the serial console output just stops after some time. It stops on the same character every time, although not the same as in the article.

I was wondering what could be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Umm, perhaps it's waiting for some input? Have you sent anything?  Try it! Exciting Adventures Await!

Comment: no, it stops mid-sentence, and i did try but either it doesn't echo anything or i have the wrong pin for RX

Comment: Hmmm, what does it say?  `This explosive device will explode in ....`  CRAP!  Oh noes!!!  Oh, probably not that, huh?

Comment: See the console output in the linked openwrt wiki article.

Comment: A quick count shows that the console output stops with approximately 4005 characters... that's suspiciously close to 4096 characters, which is likely a buffer size.  Of course, it shouldn't require any input to continue outputting the boot log, BUT... perhaps you have an incorrect connection to the RX- pin?  Speculating here: Maybe you're holding DTR/DSR/CD high/low and the system is blocked waiting for that to clear to send the rest?  What happens if you just listen on TX, but with no RX connection?

Comment: hmmm, could be , i'll have to try, tnx

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to add comment, so please excuse me for adding comments in answer box. Since your serial output stops very close to OS reading and verifying non-volatile settings, it seems like NV is set to disable uart. And likely it did not finish the last lines since they were in the tx buffer when uart got disabled.